# Geometric Proof - Three different sized circles with tangent line.

Tags: geometry

Two different sized circles lie on an line, touching each other at a point. A small circle is inscribed in the space between. How does its radius depend on the radii of the two larger circles?

Comment: I solved your problem. If you want to see my solution, show us your attempts.

Answer (score 1):

We have 3 triangles such that each are tangent to each other and each are tangent to some line.  Lets say the radius a,b are given, and we must find c.

[image]

We can use the Pythagorean theorem to find the lengths $x, y$ and $x+y$ in terms of $a,b,c$

Then $x + y = x+y$ should give you enough information to solve for $c$ in terms of $a,b.$

Answer (score 1):

Let $k_n$ be the curvature (i.e. $=r_n^{-1})$ of the $n$th circle

In virtue of [Descartes' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_theorem), the curvature $k_4$ from the radius of the smaller circle is $$k_4=k_1+k_2+k_3\pm2\sqrt{k_1k_2+k_2k_3+k_1k_3}$$

Since one of the 'circles' is a line, its curvature is $0$. Thus

> $$k_4=k_1+k_2\pm2\sqrt{k_1k_2}$$

The $\pm$ symbol depends on how the fourth circle is tangent to the others:
[image]

Since you mentioned that the fourth circle would be 'a small circle', I guess your formula turns into

> $$k_4=k_1+k_2+2\sqrt{k_1k_2}$$

Once obtained the value of $k_4$, simply use the fact that $$k_4=\frac{1}{r_4}\iff r_4=\frac{1}{k_4}$$